# What are the effects of being "Immobilized"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, conditions

I was struck by the spell Sepia Snake Sigil and now I am Immobilized. 
What does this do, can I cast spell? Can I use abilities etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Hey I can Chan pointed out in the Rules compendium p.35

**Immobilized**

> *"An immobilized creature can’t move out
> of the space it was in when it became immobilized. It otherwise
> functions normally unless it’s flying. Immobilized
> fl ying creatures that have the ability to hover can maintain
> their initial altitude. All other flying creatures subjected
> to this condition descend at a rate of 20 feet per round until
> they reach the ground, taking no falling damage."*

## However it may not be the answer you are looking for.

You should put closer attention to the first part of spell effect.

Sepia Snake Sigil:

> If the target fails its save, it is engulfed in a shimmering amber field of force[...].
>
> While trapped in the amber field of force, the subject does not age, breathe, grow hungry, sleep, or regain spells. It is preserved in a state of suspended animation, unaware of its surroundings. It can be damaged by outside forces (and perhaps even killed), since the field provides no protection against physical injury. However, a dying subject does not lose hit points or become stable until the spell ends.

Basically you are like an insect, trapped inside an amber.

Comment: Do you have an official source? This is part of d&d wikia homebrew section.

Comment: Added source backing up what I found. I'm trying to locate the original entrie in the rules books

Comment: As Hey I Can Chan pointed, the entry in the Rules Compendium:

_"Immobilized: An immobilized creature can’t move out
of the space it was in when it became immobilized. It otherwise
functions normally unless it’s fl ying. Immobilized
fl ying creatures that have the ability to hover can maintain
their initial altitude. All other flying creatures subjected
to this condition descend at a rate of 20 feet per round until
they reach the ground, taking no falling damage."_
I could post it, but it feel as stealing the answer from Hey I Can Chan

Comment: @HeyICanChan Would teleportation work vs this spell then?

Comment: The question was "What are the effects of being “Immobilized”?"
Snake Sigil seems pretty straightforward. You are not in the "Immobilized" condition. You're in stase. Period. As to know if teleport would work is another matter. You can't cast it by yourself, that for sure